# Не подключается простейший Websocket сервер

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, websocket, asyncio

Есть совсем простой код на Python(вер. 3.9):

```
import websockets
import asyncio

async def server(websocket, path):
    # Register.
    connected.add(websocket)
    try:
        async for message in websocket:
            for conn in connected:
                if conn != websocket:
                    await conn.send(f'Got a new MSG FOR YOU: {message}')
    finally:
        # Unregister.
        connected.remove(websocket)

start_server = websockets.serve(server, "localhost", 5000)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Он переотправляет сообщения от пользователя из JS-части этого дока:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Socket Thing1</title>
</head>
<body>
    Client1
    <button onclick="sendMsg()">Send Msg</button>
</body>
<script>
    // Create WebSocket connection.
    const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:5000');

    // Connection opened
    socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
        console.log('Connected to the WS Server!')
    });

    // Connection closed
    socket.addEventListener('close', function (event) {
        console.log('Disconnected from the WS Server!')
    });

    // Listen for messages
    socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
        console.log('Message from server ', event.data);
    });
    // Send a msg to the websocket
    const sendMsg = () => {
        socket.send('Hello from Client1!');
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Пытался менять порты, инициализировать через URL, нигде нет особого решения

Comment: Какую ошибку пишет?

Comment: @andreymal Console выводит WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:5000/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, весь код на руках

Answer (score -1):

Проблема в том что JS не определял const как тип переменной, а также не определял функцию sendMsg()

Cоответственно надо передвинуть тег  до кнопки в 
и изменить тип переменной socket на var

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Socket Thing1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    // Create WebSocket connection.
    var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:5000");

    // Connection opened
    socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
        console.log('Connected to the WS Server!')
    });

    // Connection closed
    socket.addEventListener('close', function (event) {
        console.log('Disconnected from the WS Server!')
    });

    // Listen for messages
    socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
        console.log('Message from server ', event.data);
    });
    // Send a msg to the websocket
    const sendMsg = () => {
        socket.send('Hello from Client1!');
    }
    </script>
    Client1
    <button onclick="sendMsg()">Send Msg</button>
</body>
</html>
```